# Is there a way to convert bitmap into instructions, or easily read it?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have code that takes an image and converts it into a bitmap. I was wondering if there was a way to save the bitmap in a separate file to be used later. I would like to also be able to open that file in plain text and not an actual image so that I can read the bitmap.
code:

```
image_file = Image.open("edge.png")
image_file = image_file.convert('1')


print(image_file.mode)
print(type(image_file.tobitmap()))

tobit_image = image_file.tobitmap() # convert image to bitmap

print(tobit_image)
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Maybe you can describe what the *"answer"* would be for a black 3 pixel by 3 pixel image with a white diagonal?

Comment: What do you mean by "read the bitmap"? Is there anything wrong with opening the image with `Image.open` and getting the data by converting it to a numpy array or through any other API?

Comment: @ImperishableNight I'm not familiar with converting to numpy array. Would I then be able to save this array as a text file?

Comment: What is your understanding of what a bitmap is? How do you expect this text file to look?

Comment: Well, yes! There is a method `np.savetxt` designed to save an array in a human-readable format if that's what you want.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm fairly new to bitmap and I may not be understanding something. I want to be able to save the data of an image so that a separate file can parse the file.

Comment: What's wrong with `edge.png`? It contains the data of the image, and it seems you've written a program that can read it..

Comment: What's your actual overall goal with this code?

Comment: @Blorgbeard my goal is to be able to draw an image that is sent to my script using the turtle module. So far I convert the image into just edge lines using OpenCV. I'm looking for a way to read these lines and convert them into drawing instructions for turtle.

Comment: Ok! You want to do "image vectorization". A bitmap is raster data, just like the png. You need vector data to be able to draw it with a turtle. Take a look here for a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Here's another link that might be helpful: http://freeconnection.blogspot.com/2013/07/vectorize-image-with-python-scikit-image.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for *"Chain Codes"*, or *"Freeman Chain Codes"*. Basically, you store a direction, which is one of the 8 points of the compass encoded as a digit at each location to tell you how to get get to the next point, i.e. which direction your turtle must move.

Try looking [here](http://speedyguy17.info/icpc/data/rmrc/2011/problems/probB/shapenumber.html) and also Googling.

OpenCV can generate them too with `findContours()`

Or, you may be looking for [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) which is a tool that converts images into vector paths.